# UrbanAirship - Update named user failed with status: 400

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

My Android app sets the UrbanAirship "Named User" after a user logs in to the app. This usually works fine, and the code looks like this:

```
UAirship.shared().getNamedUser().setId(userId);
```

When I try this for a particular userId (actually my own personal user), it always fails, and I see this in the logs:

```
UALib: Update named user failed with status: 400
```

When this happens, targeted push notifications do not reach the device. I'm worried that this issue will affect other users beyond my own. Does anybody know what causes this error? I've tried testing with a few other user accounts and haven't had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your applications go dashboard, under "APIs & Integrations" there is an options to allow setting named users from the device. Make sure thats enabled.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day :)

Comment: How can i use this in web UAirship.shared().getNamedUser().setId(userId); means named user integration in web

thanks